# How to bake normals from sphere to plane

Tags: normals, normal-map

I baked the normals from a sphere to a plane. If I change the view to lookdev it looks right. But if I change to rendered mode with a hdri enabled the reflection on the plane with the normal map looks stretched. do somebody know why?

[image: lookdev view with normal reflections]

[image: rendered view with stretched reflections]

Comment: It looks to me like the normals that are too tangential to the surface are being clamped.  This may have to do with recent "terminator artifact" fixes.  It might be interesting to see if earlier version of Blender (like 2.80) had the same problem.  As demonstrated, it's not a practical problem: using a plane for a sphere's normals is too much deviation, not something you should do.

Comment: May be from interpolation between the uvs. Try subdividing your plane in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a UV problem. Check your plane's uVs. Should be completed. Else, enter into UV mode and edit the UVs until it covers the coordinates. Also: Good thinking, you've given me a few ideas with this. BTW: How did you get correct UV-localspace object normal ? just baked Normals?